# Propensity score matching: Select relevant covariats with regression?

Tags: regression, propensity-scores, matching

I‘m performing a propensity score matching in a health economics setting. The goal is to show the effect of a certain treatment on health expenses. Is it reasonable to identify first the [covariats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariate) with the highest impact on health expenses? A matching for covariats that don't influence expenses is worthless, isn't it? What do you think?

Comment: Typical standard practice for PS recommends to include all possible covariates, including those not apparently associated with the outcome of interest.

Comment: Are you certain you need matching to begin with? Is there a reason why would one not directly use covariate adjustment? Do not throw away good data-points! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question and a colleague of mine showed me this article:

https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~john/papers/DAgostinoSIM1998.pdf

*d'Agostino, R. B. (1998). Propensity score methods for bias reduction in the comparison of a treatment to a non‐randomized control group. Statistics in medicine, 17(19), 2265-2281*

> "However, one advantage to performing the two-step procedure is that one can fit a very complicated propensity score model with interactions and higher order terms first. 
>    Since the goal of this propensity score model is to obtain the best estimated probability of treatment assignment, one is not concerned with over-parameterizing this model."